# Change collapse panel content background color

Tags: html, css, reactjs, antd

I'm using `collapse` component from `ant design`, [link](https://ant.design/components/collapse/) here. How do I change the background color of the panel? I only managed to change the color of `panel header` but not the **expanded content**. Here's the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKtRO.jpg) to my `collapse` on my project.

```py
// jsx
<Collapse className={styles.collapseStyle} expandIconPosition="right"></Collapse>

//css
.collapseStyle {
  background-color: #2f313583;
  .ant-collapse-content {
    background: #2f313583;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give `className` to Panel. And give background color to that class

For Example:

// JSX

```
<Collapse className={styles.collapseStyle} expandIconPosition="right">
    <Panel header="Header 1" key="1" className="custom-panel">
       <p>{text}</p>
    </Panel>
</Collapse>
```

// CSS

`.custom-panel { background-color: #808080 }`